# Error running Spark Main Class - Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler

Tags: error-handling, jetty, pom.xml

I am learning Mongodb for Java and I am trying to run the code below which shows jetty handler error. I tried searching for solutions in different threads of this forum but none of the solutions helps me. Please help. What am I missing?

```
package com.mongo.practice;

import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;
import spark.Spark;

public class SparkMain {


        public static void main(String[] args){

            Spark.get("/", new Route() {

                    public Object handle(final Request request, final Response response){
                    return "Hello worldfrom Spark";
                }
            });
        }

}
```

I get this error when run

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler
    at spark.embeddedserver.EmbeddedServers.initialize(EmbeddedServers.java:40)
    at spark.Service.lambda$init$2(Service.java:536)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>M101J</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I tried adding this

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.9.v20180320</version>
</dependency>
```

but it did not solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to add two dependencies. The following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.24.v20180605</version>
    </dependency>
```

The version for sl4j can varry. But the version of jetty is not flexible. I have tried with the latest version. It does not work for any other version other than this.